# Week days with case switch and enum

Tags: c, enums, switch-statement, case

I am trying to create a program with case switch and enum in C. I want to insert a week day that was preset in my enum days.
The program runs fine, but when weekday is entered I receive an error.
The code is shown below:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){

    enum days{Sunday, Monday, Tuesday, Wednesday, Thursday, Friday, Saturday};
    enum days weekDay;
    int i = 0;

    printf("Insert a week day: ");
    scanf("%s", weekDay);

    switch(weekDay){

    case Sunday:
        i=i+1;
        printf("Number of the day: %i", i);
        break;

    case Monday:
        i=i+2;
        printf("Number of the day: %i", i);
        break;

    (...)

    case Saturday:
        i=i+7;
        printf("Number of the day: %i", i);
        break;

    default:
        printf("Error. Please insert a valid week day.");
        break;

    }
```

How can I write this correctly?

Comment: _I run the program ok ?_ Does this code compile successfully without warnings ?

Comment: This `scanf("%s", weekDay);` produces warnings, you need to read those first. The format specifier `%s` expects argument of `char*` type but `weekday` is of `enum` type.

Comment: You are using scanf incorrectly, I'm sorry that I don't have time for a full answer, here are a few quick comments. 1. You don't yet understand data types in C. 2. You don't yet understand scanf. 3. You may need to learn about pointers as well. If I were you, I would avoid scanf until you know more about 1, 2, and 3.

Answer (score 1):

`scanf` with the `%s` specifier scans for strings, not `enum`s. Make sure you understand all the data types you're working with!

Unfortunately, C doesn't really care about the actual names you assign to `enum` members: they're just for your own use as the programmer, and can't be accessed by the program itself. Try something like this.

```
const char* names[] = {"Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday", NULL}; // The name of each day, in order

char buffer[16]; // A place to put the input
scanf("%15s", buffer); // Now `buffer` contains the string the user typed, to a maximum of 15 characters, stopping at the first whitespace

for(int i=0; names[i] != NULL; i++){ // Run through the names
    if(strcmp(buffer, names[i]) == 0){ // Are these two strings the same?
        printf("Day number %d \n", i+1); // Add one because you want to start with one, not zero
        return;
    }
}

printf("Sorry, that's not a valid day"); // We'll only get here if we didn't `return` earlier
```

I've stored the weekday names as strings, which the program *does* have access to. But comparing strings requires the `strcmp` function rather than a simple `==`, so I can't use a switch-case any more, and have to use a loop instead.

Comment: Hmmm... Actually I'm starting to learn programming, and I choose the C language for this.
And I've never seen this 'strcmp' function. I need to read some doc about that. But thanks, btw.

Comment: @EbertRodrigues No problem! Strings in C are a bit confusing compared to most higher-level languages, so I'd recommend sticking to numbers at first until you get the hang of the basic structure. You might also find something like Python easier to start out with: Python holds your hand a lot, while C really throws you into the deep end without a warning.